# Приём рефакторинга: извлечение метода. Как применять?

Tags: рефакторинг

Заранее прошу прощения за то, что вопрос может оказаться холиварным, однако хочется услышать *мнение* опытных разработчиков.
Итак, есть приём рефакторинга под названием `извлечение метода`. Он подразумевает, что имея большой, раздутый метод, можно извлечь из него часть кода в новый метод. Таким образом, оригинальный метод станет меньше и понятнее (в теории).

Данный приём отлично работает, когда извлечённый код будет использоваться многократно. Однако, зачастую, извлечённый код слишком специфичен, и больше нигде не используется.

Вопрос к гуру рефакторинга: по вашему мнению, стоит ли игра свеч? Нужно ли делить 50-строчную фунцию на пять 12-строчных, которые вызываются только в одном месте? Либо, стоит держать уникальный код рядом?

Comment: Хотел ответить, что да, но поймал себя на мысли, что в моем коде попадаются 50-строчные функции, в которых фрагменты подписаны комментариями. Так что мое мнение такое, что должно быть так: *с первого взгляда* на название должно быть понятно, *что* функция делает, и *с первого взгляда* на код, *как* она это делает. Если это не так, то надо рефакторить. Но вообще это такой вопрос, что у каждого будет свое понятие о красоте кода.

Comment: На пять 12-строчных я бы вряд-ли стал делить,  но если есть функционального законченный кусок строк на 20, я бы,  скорее всего,, его вынес. Ну и,, как и предыдущий оратор,  стараюсь законченные фрагменты в функции разделять пустыми строками и комментариями

Comment: По идее надо разбивать в любом случае. Разбивка делается и для вас и для других разрабов, которые будут код читать. А читаться он должен как книга (только сверху вниз), чтобы не оставалось вопросов что тут написано и для чего даже без комментариев

Comment: @trollingchar Достойно ответа, поддерживаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть желание и возможность, то с кодом стоит делать любой рефакторинг, в том числе извлечение метода (или наоборот встраивание), если при этом код становится легче читать, и нет каких-то нарушений требований проекта: бюджет, сроки, политики кодирования, принятые в команде, требования к быстродействию и т.п.

Многие концепции разработки ПО и вообще проектирования систем ставят простоту реализации на первое место по важности. Например, "[Чем хуже, тем лучше](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5)" и другие. Рискну распространить понятие "простота реализации" и на простоту чтения кода.

Добавлю еще о том, как можно оценить простоту чтения кода. Можно, например, спросить коллег. Но учитывая субъективность оценки, и то, что наиболее вероятный читатель этого кода - это вы сами (через некоторое время), я бы советовал оценить читабельность кода самостоятельно. В том случае, если есть сомнения в том, что код станет более понятным после рефакторинга, я не советую производить рефакторинг, пока сомнения не исчезнут. Этим вы сэкономите время на более полезные правки.